# Can I create multiline HTML text and convert it to objects?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a HTML structure (in this case of a metro station) and later append it in antother html file to a list of metro stations.

How can the text be recognized as an object, because when i append the text i
get a TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 is not an object.

the part of script a:

```
  const createdElement = createHtml(`
  <li class="content-card">
    <a href=${station.websiteUrl} target="_blank">
      <div class="card-img-wrapper">
        <img class="station-img" src="${station.imgUrl}" alt="Metro Station ${station.name}">
      </div>
    <div class="content-discription">
        <h2>${station.name}</h2>
        <p>${station.description}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  `)

  const savedElement = localStorage.setItem ('new-list-item', createdElement)
```

The other script:

```
const stationList = document.querySelector('#stations-list')
const newStation = localStorage.getItem('new-list-item')
stationList.appendChild(newStation)
```

I thoguth i could just append the text.

Comment: why `createHtml(`...`);` and not just the template it wraps?  OR just use the `.innerHTML` of a new `li` element in the list element (`ul` or `ol`)  Assumption `'#stations-list'` is one of those types

Answer (score 0):

localStorage return the string, so you should wrap the **savedElement** with **createHtml** before adding to DOM

Comment: I think you meant the `newStation` retrieved perhaps